# matlab: setting MarkerFaceColor in gscatter

Tags: matlab

The [man page for `gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html) indicates that only a limited set of plotting parameters can be manipulated (color, symbol / marker, marker edge color, marker size, legend visibility). How can one set additional parameters such as `MarkerFaceColor` in `gscatter`? Must one access the marker parameters at a lower level (e.g., through plot handles)? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, plot handles is the way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to capture the handle from gscatter, but it's pretty straightforward:

```
load discrim
a = gscatter(ratings(:,1),ratings(:,2),group,'br','oo')
set(a(1), 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b')
set(a(2), 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r')
```